# How to get a list of map objects from list of strings dart

Tags: dart

I have the following list with phone numbers:

```
listofnumbers = ['01225','03933']
```

and a list of map objects as:

```
 List mapofobjects = [
      {
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'phone': {
          'numbers': ['03323', '02333'], 
          'verified': true
        },
        'uid': '2BDNDD',
        'createdat': 'today..'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Mary Doe',
        'phone': {
          'numbers': ['03933', '39939'], // matches 03933 in listofnumbers
          'verified': true
        },
        'uid': '1BDNDD',
        'createdat': 'today..'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Vincin Doe',
        'phone': {
          'numbers': ['01225', '59939'], // matches 01225 in listofnumbers
          'verified': true
        },
        'uid': 'XBDNDD',
        'createdat': 'today..'
      }
    ];
```

How can I convert the listofnumbers into a list of map objects using each listofnumbers item as join.

I should get something like this for the listofnumbers of two numbers:

```
finalList =  List mapofobjects = [
      {
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'phone': {
          'numbers': ['03323', '02333'],
          'verified': true
        },
        'uid': '1BDNDD',
        'createdat': 'today..'
      },
      {
        'name': 'Vincin Doe',
        'phone': {
          'numbers': ['01225', '59939'],
          'verified': true
        },
        'uid': 'XBDNDD',
        'createdat': 'today..'
      }
    ];
```

With each object matching/replacing a listofnumbers of item when phone['numbers'] contains the item.

Comment: Why John Doe? Neither of his numbers are part of your `listofnumbers`? I think it should be "Mary Doe" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two `forEach` to get this result, like this:

```
    List finallist = [];

    listofnumbers.forEach((element) {
      mapofobjects.forEach((e) => {
            if (e['phone']['numbers'].contains(element))
              finallist.add(e)
          });
    });
   print(finallist.length.toString());
```

the result is: **2**

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
final finalList = [
  ...mapofobjects.where((dynamic object) =>
      object['phone']['numbers'].any((phone) => listofnumbers.contains(phone)))
];

finalList.forEach(print);
// {name: Mary Doe, phone: {numbers: [03933, 39939], verified: true}, uid: 1BDNDD, createdat: today..}
// {name: Vincin Doe, phone: {numbers: [01225, 59939], verified: true}, uid: XBDNDD, createdat: today..}
```